# In-memory vs Caching for an ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net, caching, in-memory-database

My web application is using a SQL Server database that has around 2000 rows. I wanted to know if its better to load all the DB  to the RAM (Store it in a static var) and query it using ASP.NET LINQ. I need it only for read operations. I think that the amount of RAM needed is not very high at all. I think it can speed up the application considerably.

I wanted to know if it's a good option, instead of caching the data?

Comment: Are you sure that reading those 2000 rows is slow? Is it your bottleneck? Then move it to a static var.

Comment: Two questions - 1. What exactly do you think the difference between keeping something in memory and caching something is? 2. What is `ASP.NET LINQ` ?

Comment: as asawyer alludes to, caching (asp.net cache object) and storing in memory are the same. The benefit of the asp.net cache object is that alot of the common needs have already been thought of and addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database that small is already in memory on your server, no need to do it twice.

Answer (score 1):

Looks Ok to me considering the details you have provided. The difference performance wise shouldn't be huge, though.

Answer (score 0):

you need a caching product when your database is huge in size and it becomes bottleneck as frequent trips to the DB to complete a request may result in performance decline. if the DB is of the size as you've mentioned, there is no need of it.